# Spring Authorization Server: Testing OAuth flow with redirects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm writing an integration test for my OAuth flow built with Spring Authorization Server version 0.2.1. I'd like to test that a call to the authorize route redirects to the a 'callback' controller that I've embedded in the test. This works with either curl, postman or even an OAuth client - however I just want to make it work in an integration test.

Note: I have a slightly customised flow, in that the authorization principal is created with an incoming JWT from another application. This works by utilising an injected `BearerTokenResolver` as well as configuring my authorization server to act also as a resource server to handle authentication through that JWT with `oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)`. This basically means I can trigger an OAuth flow from the point of view from an authenticated user if I redirect a `/login` call that has all the oauth options as well as the JWT mentioned previously. Then redirect that to `/oauth2/authorize` -- this all works works outside of a test.

The test has the following (rough) structure:

```
@LocalServerPort  // using SpringBootTest with webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
private int port;

// Capture the redirect that has the auth code
// if it returns the
@RestController
public static class TestRegisteredCallback {
    @GetMapping("/callback")
    public String callback(@RequestParam String code, @RequestParam String state){
        return code;
    }
}

@Test
public void canGetAccessCode_existingConsent() throws Exception {
    // given an existing client
    Client client = setupNewClient();
    client.setRedirectUris(String.format("http://127.0.0.1:%s/callback", port));
    clientRepository.save(client);

    // and a consent against that client
    authorizationConsentRepository.save(setupNewConsent());
    // and a registered test controller for that clients callback

    String constructingUrl = String.format("/login?response_type=code" +
            "&client_id=clientid" +
            "&scope=read" +
            "&state=teststate" +
            "&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:%s/callback" +
            "&nonce=testnonce" +
            "&access_token=%s", port, JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN);

    String url = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromUriString(constructingUrl)
            .build()
            .encode()
            .toUri().toString();

    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=0778F764F69C8C17162D76EFD69F635C");
    HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity(null, requestHeaders);

    // call the /login - login will authenticate using provided JWT
    ResultActions resultActions = this.mockMvc
            .perform(get(url)
                .headers(requestHeaders)
            )
            .andDo(print());
    MvcResult result = resultActions.andReturn();

    // follow the redirect to /auth2/authorize
    ResultActions action2 = this.mockMvc.perform(
            get(
                    result.getResponse()
                            .getHeader("Location"))
                    .headers(requestHeaders)
                    )
            .andDo(print());
    MvcResult authorizeResult = action2.andReturn();
    
    // authorizeResult comes back as a 401 :(
   // should come as 302 to Location http://127.0.0.1:%s/callback ?
}
```

I **do** have the `/callback` route permitted in the filter chain:

```
antMatchers("/callback/**").permitAll()
```

The same flow, but written using curl works perfectly. Debugging SAS when running from curl / actual client the principal is correctly set to `JwtAuthenticationToken` *after* and before the redirect.

When debugging SAS I've noticed for the code path that's not working the `authorizationCodeRequestAuthentication` object's principal is an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` - where as for the working codepath, the principal is a `JwtAuthenticationToken`

I thought it might be due to the session? Though, I've tried to ensure that the session is the same for the call to `/login` and for when the redirect is followed and think that works, as see the same cookie in debug.

I'm using `print()` in the mvc calls - here's the output:

Call to /login, authenticate and redirect to /oauth2/authorize as expected:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /login
       Parameters = {response_type=[code], client_id=[clientid], scope=[read], state=[teststate], redirect_uri=[http://127.0.0.1:63440/callback], nonce=[testnonce], access_token=[eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c]}
          Headers = [Cookie:"JSESSIONID=0778F764F69C8C17162D76EFD69F635C"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=JwtAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt@3ee32622, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[]]]}

Handler:
             Type = com.fanduel.oauthservice.auth.LoginRedirectController
           Method = com.fanduel.oauthservice.auth.LoginRedirectController#login(String, String, String, String, String, String, Authentication, HttpServletRequest, HttpSession)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = redirect:/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=clientid&scope=read&state=teststate&nonce=testnonce&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:63440/callback
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 302
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Language:"en", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", Location:"/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=clientid&scope=read&state=teststate&nonce=testnonce&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:63440/callback"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = /oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=clientid&scope=read&state=teststate&nonce=testnonce&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:63440/callback
          Cookies = []
```

Follow redirect to `/oauth2/authorize` - but run into 401 when expecting 302

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /oauth2/authorize
       Parameters = {response_type=[code], client_id=[clientid], scope=[read], state=[teststate], nonce=[testnonce], redirect_uri=[http://127.0.0.1:63440/callback]}
          Headers = [Cookie:"JSESSIONID=0778F764F69C8C17162D76EFD69F635C"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST=DefaultSavedRequest [http://localhost/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=clientid&scope=read&state=teststate&nonce=testnonce&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:63440/callback]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = null
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to force the session to maintain between `mockMvc` calls. Setting the cookie and keeping it the same across redirects didn't seem to work.

However I managed to get the session to go across the calls by just grabbing it on the first request and setting it for subsequent requests.

```
        // first call - expect to redirect
        MvcResult loginResult = this.mockMvc
                .perform(get(url))
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn();

        String redirectUrl = loginResult.getResponse().getHeader("Location");

        // GRAB THE SESSION - this is what fixed my problem. mockmvc doesn't maintain sessions for you.
        MockHttpSession session = (MockHttpSession) loginResult.getRequest().getSession();

        // follow redirect
        MvcResult authorizeResult = this.mockMvc
                .perform(get(redirectUrl).session(session)) // <--- now use that session
                .andDo(print())
                .andReturn();
```